# Docker arguments for Mesos

Tags: docker, containers, mesos, mesosphere

I am trying to execute a docker container in a Mesos cluster. The effective docker command I want to execute is:

```
docker run -it -v /home/me:/home/jovyan/work -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook
```

I understand the command will be of the form:

```
mesos-execute --containerizer=docker --master=127.0.0.1:9090 --name=test --docker_image=jupyter/pyspark-notebook --command="start-notebook.sh" --resources="cpus:8"
```

How do I pass in the equivalents of the `-p` and the `-v` arguments to the `memos-execute` command?

Currently, I am running a vanilla Mesos cluster without any of the added services like Marathon running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [mesos-execute](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.4.0/src/cli/execute.cpp#L106-L139)

> The value could be a JSON-formatted string of [`TaskInfo`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.4.0/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L1900) or a file path containing the JSON-formatted [`TaskInfo`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.4.0/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L1900). Path must be of the form `file:///path/to/file` or `/path/to/file`.
>
> See the [`TaskInfo`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.4.0/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L1900) message in [`mesos.proto`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/include/mesos/mesos.proto) for the expected format. NOTE: `agent_id` need not to be set.

TaskInfo contains filed for container configuration called [`ContainerInfo`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.4.0/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L2807-L2818) where you can configure [`port mappings`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.4.0/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L2839-L2846).

For any other custom options you can use [`Parameters`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.4.0/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L2839)

```
// Allowing arbitrary parameters to be passed to docker CLI.
// Note that anything passed to this field is not guaranteed
// to be supported moving forward, as we might move away from
// the docker CLI.
repeated Parameter parameters = 5;
```